# Syncing is ridiculously slow

Tags: couchbase, pouchdb

We are using pouchdb with couchbase in my angular web app. We have around 100k documents on the server. The initial sync takes about 30 minutes on a stable and excellent internet connection. I have noticed that there is an http call per document in many instances where us it reports error 406 unsupported error when pouch tries bulk_get via POST method.

Is there anything I can do to speed the sync up? Or it is designed like that and I have to live with it? The couchbase version is 2.1 but I don't mind upgrading it to the latest version.

Comment: What are your sync options? For example, `batches_limit`, `batch_size`, `timeout`? Are there large attachments?

Comment: @RamblinRose there are no attachments at all. I guess I can timeout but not sure about the others...the thing is I want the data to be downloaded fully.

Comment: It's difficult to provide answers as the question is a bit broad.  I'd watch [issue #8015](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/8015) on github and poke around there in general.